# Can I keep my Core data store on the Bundle if its readonly

Tags: iphone, ios

The usual way to use a core data store is to copy it into the documents directory on first launch.

However, with the advent of iOS 5, [users can choose to have the documents directory synced](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1), wich has caused some [problems](http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning). Basically, the documents directory should not have too much data in.

Now I have a large core data store that does not need to be changed.  So my question is, will it let me open the store from the bundle if I dont call the save method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put read-only Core Data stores in the bundle and access them just fine. As long as you never have to change the store, you're OK. If your data ever needs to change, you'll have to update the binary.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Application Support directory. It is supposed to store all application specific support data.

Comment: This is for iOS, is the Application Support directory a Mac feature?

Comment: Application Support wouldn't be a good choice — it's backed up to iCloud. I don't know the answer to the question regarding opening the Core Data file in the bundle (just try it and see if it works?), but if you can't do that then put it in Caches. You'll need to check on app launch to make sure it is still there, and if not then copy it over from your bundle again.