# How to store immutable text in iOS app (to be available at first and every launch)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-data

I am new to iOS Programming, and have very little experience in programming in general (high school level only). Recently signed up for an iOS Developer account and want to create a Movie Quotes app.

I want to employ Core Data to save more than 300,000 quotes which will have these entities.
*The text file's size is around 8 MB.*

*Quotes*:
Att: theQuote
Rel: saidByCharacter, fromMovie

*Movies*:
Att: movieName, moviePosterLink
Rel: quotesFromThisMovie (to-many), characters (to-many)

*MovieCharacter*:
Att: characterName
Rel: fromMovie

Obviously all this data has to be included within the app. Also there will be a folder containing more than 50,000 small images for the movie posters.

My question is **how can I store textual info inside the app (using Core Data)?**

I have read Apple's Core Data Tutorial for iOS, Core Data Programming Guide, watched Stanford's iOS course, read Stephen Kochan's book on Objective-C, and searched on the Internet for some info regarding this really introductory task, but have found nothing. Am wondering if this thing is so ridiculously easy that it doesn't need a tutorial...

Comment: watch Apple WWDC video on Core data, it has most of your answers.

Comment: It is not uncommon to create an app just to import the data from the textfile to core data and then bundle the already populated database.

Comment: If you want it to be immutable you don't need to use Core-Data, you can store the file directly in your apps bundle (.txt, .xml, etc.). If you store data here, you will be able to read it but not write to it.

Comment: What @NSPostWhenIdle said can still be done with [CoreData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847309/can-i-keep-my-core-data-store-on-the-bundle-if-its-readonly) or directly with SQLite. I am sure you would rather run a query than search through 300,000 quotes yourself.

Comment: @Joe Wow I must have missed that detail somehow... I guess Core Data or SQL would be the way to go with that much data!

Comment: Joe: Could you possibly point me to a tutorial on how to do that importing thing? And how to include it in a bundle?
Wouldn't it be the same as just having it in an XML file and let it be parsed?

Comment: @codejunkie Could you please post the link to the exact video you are referring to? I have seen What's New in Core Data in iOS 5. It certainly didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ray Wenderlich's core data tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) - in particular [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data) which is about how to add seed data to your app.

Comment: What is provided in the part of the tutorial is covered very clearly in lecture 13 and 14 of the Stanford iOS 5 course by Paul (Hagerty) and I understood it completely.

But the part, which is MY ACTUAL QUERY, is where they have taken a shortcut and used code which seems to me like cheating/shortcut. It uses Python and I was wondering how to do it using XCode, Objective C and iOS 5 APIs only. Or it can't be done?? (I am a noob, so please be tolerant!)

Answer (score 0):

Should you choose to go with Core Data--

Ray Wenderlich's tutorial is pretty good:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

However, working with Core Data directly requires a LOT of boiler plate code, which is kind of a pain. To address this, Magical Record (and helper classes Magical Import) was created, and it really simplifies the process:

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

However, as Wenderlich's second tutorial on "Preloading Data" talks about, you're going to need some way to get the data into Core Data first.

To do this, you can use a flat file (such as sqlite/sqlite3 file) within the app's bundle, or you can setup a web service (for content that changes over time, controlled by you, which isn't possible if you bundle it into the app).

You can also find a tutorial on creating a web service drive app on Wenderlich's site, too.

Cheers!