# Best way to store display and search for Text for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, core-data, text

I'm trying to build an iOS application that has to store lots of text (immutable) data (about 500 pages of a book) and should have the following functionalities:

1. Organize text into chapters and display
2. Search for words and autocomplete. Search results should be based on most number of   occurrences of a word. The search functionality is key for the application.

Based on this i wanted to know a couple of things

1. Whats the best way to store and retrieve this data and to perform a search (everything is local , no data on a server)?
2. Are there any third party frameworks that help you to do this in a faster way?

I've looked at this already

[How to store immutable text in iOS app (to be available at first and every launch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264705/how-to-store-immutable-text-in-ios-app-to-be-available-at-first-and-every-launc)

And this post suggests the use of CoreData and MagicRecord. Is this enough for me to integrate the search functionality as well?

More information on the same and other resources/tools/third party frameworks would be helpful!